# Using session storage on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, session-variables

The libraries I have seen and use allow to store on local storage, but is there a way to store data easily on session storage with Flutter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
[flutter_session_manager 1.0.3] https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session_manager
but,it also depends upon *shared_preferences* package

Comment: This stores in Local Storage too. Besides it hasn't been updated in almost 2 years

Comment: You can use windows.sessionStorage from 'dart:html' package
or else checkout package : https://pub.dev/packages/session_storage. 
Checkit out if it satisfy your requirement.